# Azure DevOps CI Pipeline - Using variables for dynamic repository checkout

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use an Azure DevOps CI Pipeline to validate code of other repositories while the pull request.

Regarding to this, I have created a central repository with a `.yml`-file for linting the powershell code of another repository.

As this will be a `Branch Policy` > `Build Validation`-task, I need to checkout the central repository and the repository which I would like to check.

Multiple hardcoded repository checkout isn't that problem.
So far, so good.

The problem is, to make the to be checked repository checkout dynamic :(

**What am I trying to do?**

I am trying to get the `REPOSITORYNAME` with RegEx in Powershell, set it as a variable and trying to checkout repository dynamically:

[System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) = https://XXX@dev.azure.com/YYY/ZZZ/_git/REPOSITORYNAME

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - powershell: |
      $regex = [regex]::Match($env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEREPOSITORYURI, "/([^/]+)$")
      $repositoryName = $regex.Groups[1].Value
      Write-Host $repositoryName
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=repositoryName;]$repositoryName"
      Write-Host "Variable 'repositoryName' has been set."
    displayName: 'Set variable(s) with PowerShell'
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: git://$(SYSTEM.TEAMPROJECT)/$(repositoryName)@$(SYSTEM.PULLREQUEST.TARGETBRANCHNAME) # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

As well, I tried to use another method of checkout, `Condition` and `if`-statement without success.

I am wondering why the `$(repositoryName)` isn't working as expected?

Any suggestions?